# Limit in the number of aggregated characters after running GROUP_CONCAT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I am using GROUP_CONCAT in my query to collect some IDs. Imagine I have two columns as follow:

```
user_id
item
```

The code looks like this:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item) AS all_items_by_user
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

However, I noticed that the `all_items_by_user` column can accommodate up to a certain number of characters in each cell. This limit is around 1100 in my case, whereas I expect at least 10 times more. I wondered whether there is any way to increase this limit?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by `group_concat_max_len`, a system variable.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) describes how to change the value and what it really means.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!
For the record:
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=ANY_LENGTH